# What are the best practices for creating a "settings" model in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my first project using Laravel (I'm starting with 5.2). I'm building a self managed website. There's an admin that should save site settings for using later in the website. Eg: Background color, social networks, carousel with pictures, products, etc.

My first try was creating a model "Setting" with: `id | key (unique) | value`. When I tried to save social networks (to display in the site header), I realized I'd have to save in "value" a json with URL, title, etc... Ugly implementation for a relational model, so I came to the conclussion it was bad. I created a sepparated model SocialNetwork with: `id | URL | image | name`.

Now I'm thinking in loading all these models at once in my BaseController so I can have it through all controllers, but I'm not sure it's correct. I mean, an array `$settings` with all models as part of it:

```
abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $settings;
    ...

    public function __construct(...)
    {
        $this->settings = [
            'backgroundColor' => 'red',
            'socialNetworks' => SocialNetwork::all(),
            'other' => Other::all(),
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

It looks horrible to me, but I'm lost with this framework and I don't know what's the best I could do to deal with this.
Someone told me about service providers, but I'm trying to figure out the advantages of it and the best approach to be able to also made use of these models (to save data) and I don't get it.

I'm not asking for explicit code (it would be nice however), I'll investigate it after understanding the approach, but some tips or conceptual help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question. Recently i did for one of my Code Canyon product ([Krisma CMS Script](https://codecanyon.net/item/krisma-cms-script/17523033)) and my approach was as below.

1) Created a Service Provider

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->header();
        $this->intro();
        $this->about();
        $this->resume();
        $this->portfolio();
        $this->services();
        $this->stats();
        $this->contact();
        $this->footer();
        $this->section();
        $this->codesetting();
        $this->customizer();
    }
```

Each of this function which is called in the boot is declared in the Provider Class below boot function.
e.g for Header Section i fetched data from DB via Header Model and shared it globally which can be accessed any where in your app.

```
$section = Section ::find(1);
view()->share('section ', $section);
```

2) Created a table for each section i.e about, intro etc and inserted the values which i want to modify.

3) Now in the admin panel create a form for changes/modifications and update the desired section properties.

4) Fetch the data in your view. Suppose if the user has changed the background color from admin panel to RED, so print out that variable right in your view `style : {{ $sectionname->color }}`

5) That's it i hope it gives you a better idea of how settings can be implemented and i did this for my Product, may be there is a better way but up to now this is what i found in my research and works perfect for me.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. I see you shared the data directly to the view from each declared function below boot as you says. My question is: how do you access every instance to work inside a controller? Is there a "clean" way to have all of them in a single object, like "Settings"? And more important, would it be ok? I mean, I like to work in an orderly scenario where every thing belongs to a group (if needs to) and I think it should be part of a group. What do you think?

Comment: First once you shared object like the above method you can access it anywhere, i.e weather in Controller or in view. 2nd you said if you want to access it just from settings ( one object) that can be done if you want to save all your fields in just one table and then share it BUT if you have to many section as in my case i would recommend different tables.Moreover you said that it would be ok or not? I will say that i used in my product which was approved by codecanyon and codecanyon approve things which has high standad and well code standards. + may be there is a better approach than this.

Comment: What I meant was that it looks better (just to me and because I thought in it as a big config saved in database) if it were a single object with properties and nested objects... but I don't know Laravel so I don't know if I'm making a mistake thinking like that. It's also easier to examine all settings if they are all together in a single place. A single table is not an option however, so this is why I'm stuck here and asking for help. BTW thank you for your time, this solution looks good.

Comment: I am also interested btw nice question.