# What is the best way to set the title and logo of a page globally?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm letting the user choose the title and logo of the site, and storing it in the database at, but I'm having trouble trying to "propagate" those changes across the whole page. Is there any way to do so?

Maybe with `config('title')`?

I know there's something similar in the Laravel docs, but it only does it for the view you set the `@section('title')` at.

This is my first post, so I'd take any suggestions for future questions. Also, let me know if you need more info. Thanks :)

Comment: I think I can help you. Do you use several blade templates, or just one ? Do you use a controller to return the view or do you return it directly from the routes file (`routes/web.php`)

Answer (score 0):

```
 //in your app.blade.php
<title>
    {{ config('app.name', 'your app name') }}
</title>
<link rel="icon" href="{{url("your_logo_url")}}">
```

Comment: That didn't work. I put a variable called ```title``` in ```config/app.php``` file and I can indeed reference it  ```{{ config('app.title' }}```, but I need to be able to update this value when the user inputs a new title. Is there a way? Thanks for the help.

I'm a newbie using Laravel, so sorry if this is a bit obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it using this [answer] ([What are the best practices for creating a "settings" model in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111507/what-are-the-best-practices-for-creating-a-settings-model-in-laravel-5?rq=1)) from another post and [this video](https://youtu.be/7QWZxjgvEQc).

I created a seed to populate my options table. After that, I also created a composer:

**SiteOptionsComposer**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\View\Composers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Repositories\SiteOptionsRepository;

class SiteOptionsComposer
{
    protected $siteOptionsRepository;

    public function __construct(SiteOptionsRepository $siteOptionsRepo)
    {
        // Dependencies automatically resolved by service container...
        $this->siteOptionsRepository = $siteOptionsRepo;
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('siteOptions', $this->siteOptionsRepository->first());
    }
}
```

Then, in my `SiteOptionsServiceProvider` I share it with the folder in which I stored my view partials:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Http\View\Composers\SiteOptionsComposer;

class SiteOptionsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('partials.shared.*', SiteOptionsComposer::class);
    }
}
```

**Note:** I'm using repositories.

This means all my templates in this folder will be able to access my siteOptions variable. e.g.:

My `title.blade.php` in my `partials.shared` folder

```php
<title>{{ $siteOptions->site_name }}</title>
```

After this, I can just include it wherever I need it, like this:

```php
@include('partials.shared.title')
```